# How to generate random data with R to create a positive or negative skewed curve?

Tags: r

How can I create randomized data to create a positive or negative skewed curve in `R` and show them with `hist()`.

Comment: Read about "skew": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution

Comment: an easy thing to do is to transform Normal deviates, e.g. `rnorm(1000)^2` for right-skewed or `sqrt(rnorm(1000))` for left-skewed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is straightforward to plot a skewed distribution with the beta distribution `rbeta()`.
The beta distribution takes values from 0 to 1. If you want can rescale the data by multiplying it by a constant.
You can generate right and left skewness by adjusting the `shape1` and `shape1` parameters

```
set.seed(5)
#left skewness 
hist(rbeta(100000,100,1)*10)
#right skewness 
hist(rbeta(100000,1,100)*10)
```

Comment: This works great. Is there also a way to control the standard deviation?